# How to use a list of strings as a variable in Mathematica 8?

Tags: string, list, wolfram-mathematica

I believe my question to be pretty simple, I just cannot find a solution, I have exhausted help docs looking for a similar situation.

I have a list of strings which are city names, I want to set up a function/expression that uses each name in the list in the function and then outputs the results in a table.  I am a complete novice when it comes to writing in the Mathematica language, or any language at all for that matter.  So bear with me if I use the wrong terms.  Here is a sample of what I have written so far.

```
Module[
 {dateRange, mean, cdd, hdd, station, country, location, population, 
  GDPPerCapita,
  reference = (65 - 32)/1.8, cumList},


 cityLIST = CityData[#, "Name"] & /@ CityData[];


 station =;
 country = CityData[station, "Country"];
 population = CityData[station, "Population"];
 location = CityData[station, "Coordinates"];
 GDPPerCapita = CountryData[country, "GDPPerCapita"];
 dateRange = {{2011, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Day"};
 mean = WeatherData[station, "MeanTemperature", dateRange];
 cdd = Join[Transpose[{mean[[All, 1]]}], 
   Transpose[{Max[# - reference, 0] & /@ mean[[All, 2]]}], 2];
 hdd = Join[Transpose[{mean[[All, 1]]}], 
   Transpose[{Min[# - reference, 0] & /@ mean[[All, 2]]}], 2];
 cumList = Transpose[{Join[
     Transpose[{cdd[[All, 1]]}],
     Transpose[{Drop[FoldList[Plus, 0, cdd[[All, 2]] + hdd[[All, 2]]],
         1]}],
     2]}];


 Grid[station, country, location, population, GDPPerCapita, 
  Last[cumList]]]
```

The cityList is the list of inputs I want to use.  I want the items in cityList to become the variable for station.  I then want all of this to output to a table (the grid I listed above is just a place holder).  I apologize in advance because this is some pretty basic stuff, I just have not been able to find a way to make it work.  Note that I am using data from Mathematica's curated datasets... cityData, countryData, and WeatherData.

If anybody on here has some helpful tricks for me I would truly appreciate it!

Comment: Hi there,could  you give a description and sample of exactly the output you want. Quick observations. `cumList`, as it is part of `reference`  seems to be used before any value has been assigned to it. `station=;`  isn't a valid statement and so no value is given to station before you use it.  One tip which is useful in programming. Is start with the most simple part of what you want to do, maybe just one statement, make that work, then add a little more functionality and mate that work and so on, until you get where you want to be. That way you can be reasonably sure that each sub part works.

Comment: @image_doctor, I want the output to be columns of city, country, population, gdppercapita, cdd, hdd, and the cumulative, and the rows to have a record for every city from citylist. I'm sorry I should have pointed out that using a city name such as "NewYork" after station for example will yield a result like this : Grid["Chicago", "UnitedStates", {41.8375511`, -87.6818441`}, 2695598, \ 45230.20468787806`, {{{2011, 12, 31}, -2842.4066666666736`}}] Those are the results I want, I'm just not sure how to "cycle" through all the cities and to output the table. And thanks for your response!

Comment: @image_doctor The statements work for one city set to "Station" just not for the list that i want to use for station :cityLIST = CityData[#, "Name"] & /@ CityData[]; The code I put in the previous question was just what I happened to be working on at the time, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: A common way to build functionality in Mathematica is to `Map` a function over a list. So you would write a function which returns the data you need and then do myFunc/@{city1name,city2name,...,cityNname}. Where `/@` is a shorthand for the `Map` function. In  your case the city names are in `cityList`.

Comment: Is `station` intended to be a weather station   or a name of a city ?

Comment: @image_doctor it's intended to be the name of a city, you use the city name to call the weather data for that particular geographic location, in this case the mean temp over the specified date range.

Comment: OK .. I was slightly confused as WeatherData normally uses a weather station name which is what I thought you meant by the variable `station`, but if you use a city name you get the most relevant weather station data. Do you want the geographic location of the city or the nearest weather station ?

Comment: @image_doctor well by using the city name i can also call the lat/long of the city center. I want it for the city so i can do population sorts and all kinds of things when I am building a map later on.  It is for a large scale map, not meant to be super accurate.

Comment: @image_doctor  Sorry to ask so many questions.  I am not quite sure how to make this function.  It is unlike anything I have been able to find in the examples for building functions, because all of the other local variables depend on the value to be used from cityList.  I was hoping you might give me another hint as to how to start building that function..?  Like I said, complete beginner, so the help you have given has been great.  Thanks again!

Comment: That's fine questions are what this site is about, right :) Can you run me through want you want hdd, cdd and cumList to do ?

Comment: @image_doctor Hdd is a heating degree day, cdd is a cooling degree day, a degree day is the difference compared baseline temp of 65 F (temp you would keep the inside of your house) cumList is just the cumulative value of all degree days for the year.   Those items work well if just given a station value.

Comment: Do you just want the last value from cumList?

Comment: yes, my math is currently incorrect for hdd, but yes, i just need the cumulative for the whole year.. so Dec 31st.

Comment: the hdd should read 

hdd = Join[Transpose[{mean[[All, 1]]}], 
   Transpose[{Min[reference - #, 0] & /@ mean[[All, 2]]}], 2];

Comment: Thanks, have I got this right: hdd is Min[Ref - value,0] and cdd is Max[Value - Ref,0] , so if Value = 10 and ref =3, we have {cdd,hdd} = {Max[10-3,0],Min[3-10,0]} = {7,-7}. If you then add them they sum to zero, all others values are zero, so cumList is zero for all values ?

Comment: By the way, if you have further questions about Mathematica, you might want to ask them over on the [dedicated StackExchange site for Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @image_doctor Sorry I was out for a few days, the hdd should have been max(ref-#,0), hdd and cdd should never yield a negative, should always be zero or the higher number.  The cumlist is the total number of hdd and cdd for the entire year for that specific city.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Mathematica installed on this machine, so this is likely to be a syntactically-deformed answer.

One useful trick with Mathematica and operations on lists is first to define a function which operates on the type of element of your list.  In your case you want a function such as:

```
writeARowOfMyTable[city_String]:=...
```

Once you have that function you can apply it to a list of city names in a variety of ways.  One way is to give the function the attribute `Listable` (check the docs) which will mean that a call such as

```
writeARowOfMyTable[listOfCityNames_List]
```

will return the rows for every city in the list.  Another approach would be to use `Map` or `Apply`, again, check the documentation.

That just leaves you to write the function `writeARowOfMyTable[]`.  I see from one of your comments that you have done this.  All I'd suggest, then, is to wrap your code into a module, like this:

```
writeARowOfMyTable[city_String] := Module[{localVariablesGoHere},codeGoesHere]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an outline for the solution:

A function to gather the data for each city you want:

```
GetData[city_List] := {city, 
  CityData[city // First, "Population"], 
  CountryData[city // Last, "GDPPerCapita"], 
  CityData[city, "Coordinates"], 
  WeatherData[First@city, 
     "MeanTemperature", {{2011, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Day"}][[All, 2]] // Mean}
```

Map the function to cities you want, in this case all of those available:

```
res=GetData/@CityData[];
```

Here is the output for the first 10 cities:

```
GetData /@ (CityData[][[1 ;; 10]]) // TableForm
```

Be warned though, you might have to deal with some missing data.

[image: Mathematica graphics]